# UIActivityIndicatorView not stop in iphone app

Tags: iphone, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using UIActivityIndicatorView in iphone application but it is not stopping
Its animating not stopping. I am uploading data to server in self uploadMethod

View Did Load MEthod

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {


    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;



   CereniaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CereniaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

   activityImageView.hidden=YES;
       activityView.hidden=YES;
   int mytestcount=appDelegate.rowCount;

   NSString*test=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",mytestcount];

  if ([test isEqualToString:@"0"]) {


    NSLog(@" No dta ot upload %d",mytestcount);

  }

 else {

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startActivity:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

       [self uploadData];

    }

  [super viewDidLoad];




[self stopData];    

}
```

Animation Stop method

```
    -(void)stopData{


[activityView stopAnimating];
activityView.hidden=YES;

activityImageView.hidden=YES;


   }
```

Start Animation Method

```
    -(void)startActivity:(id)sender
   {

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];



    activityImageView.hidden=NO;
    activityView.hidden=NO;

   [activityView startAnimating];
   [pool release];

  }
```

Upload data method

```
   -(void)uploadData{

CereniaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CereniaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

for (int i=0; i<appDelegate.coffeeArray.count; i++) {




    Coffee*coffeeObj=[appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:i];



    int mynumber=coffeeObj.participant_Id;
    NSString*question_id=coffeeObj.question_Id;
    NSString*answer_text=coffeeObj.answer_text;
    NSString*answer_option=coffeeObj.answer_option;

    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"participant_id=%d&question_id=%@&answer_text=%@&answer_option=%@",mynumber,question_id,answer_text,answer_option];




    NSLog(post);
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/emrapp/SyncSurveyTest.php"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",data);


     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put `[activityView stopAnimating];`

Comment: i am puting but then also not stoping where may i put this

Comment: where may i use this line so that after uploading this should stop

Comment: again not working in this it is not animating when view is loaded

Comment: You might have put the stopAnimating in the ViewDidLoad thatz why it wont work... Put it after ur method has been executed....

Comment: if ([test isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
  
  
  NSLog(@" No dta ot upload %d",mytestcount);
  
 }
 
 
 
 else {

  
  
  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startActivity:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
        [self uploadData];
  


  
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 
    [super viewDidLoad];

    
 
 
 [self stopData];

Comment: i am doing like this after method

Answer (score 0):

Activity.h

//Declare Activity indicator in h File and in Xib add Activity indicator and conneect it

`IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activity;`

Activity.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self startActivity];
}

-(void)startActivity{



    activity.hidden=NO;

    [activity startAnimating];
    [self uploadData];
    [self stopData];

}

-(void)uploadData
{
    NSLog(@"Uploading...");
}

-(void)stopData
{
    [activity stopAnimating];
    activity.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: i also know this where to write this so that after uploading data it should stop

Comment: Do one thing in your upload data method after uplaoding data stop activity indicator. And debug the code that startactivity method is calling again after stopping animation

Comment: if i am stopping animation then its not animating from start also when view is loaded

Comment: It is very simple. When you start uploading data call method startactivity to start animating and after data upload call method stop activity it will stop animating. And whenever you want to start acitivity simply call this method (start activity) to start animation

Comment: i am doing like this but it not happening

Comment: ok copy and paste your complete code for doing this i'll edit it

Comment: I have edited your answer for calling method for start activity.This happnes due to nsthread. your activity runs in background.

Comment: instead of calling NSThread for Start Activity do only [self startActvity] and call this method like -(void)startActivity. this will sove problem

Comment: i thins problem is that data is not uploading and we are stoping the animating that is why it is not showing is there any method to show this thing and hide

Comment: No buddy there is no relation with data not uploading i created test project here and doing the same thing its working fine. Problem is with the Nsthread method using nsthread means your process will run in background so stop that method and use void method

Comment: i am using void method but still same issue can you post your code which you tested

Comment: I am also doing like this but i don't know why it is not working

Comment: @ShahzadBaloch make it again using a UIActivityIndicator Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the property hidesWhenStopped for activity indicator

Comment: If you have added activity indicator in .xib then you can enable this property from there. You can add this property in viewDidLoad Otherwise.Just Write activityview.hidesWhenStopped=YES;

Comment: Add [activityview stopAnimating]; where you receive the response from server or at connectionDidFinishLoading (If you are using connection delegates). Stopping will automatically hide the indicator if you have used the above property